# Getting Node to work on windows 7 enterprise

Tags: node.js, crash

For the better part of a day now I've been trying to get node.js to work on my computer.
Even though I get no errors during installation, whenever i try to run node or npm from the command line I only get the error "Evented I/O for V8 JavaScript has stopped working" and then nothing happens.

I really have no clue why it isn't working and what I have to do to get it to work! Has anyone else ever had the same problem and were you able to fix it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was with ansicon which I installed together with cucumber.
I was able to fix the problem by running "ansicon -u" in my x64 folder